# Split a string and print out each word

Tags: c

I've been given a task where the user inputs a line of text. The program splits each word when it reaches a comma. Once that is done it simply prints out each word on a new line. For example:

Please enter a line of text: `Mary,had,a,little,lamb`

```
Mary
had
a
little
lamb
```

I can't use `strtok()` because it's not allowed for this task. I can use:

`printf()`, `fprintf()`, `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()`, `fgets()`, `snprintf()`, `strncpy()`, `strncat()`, `strncmp()`, `strdup()`, `strlen()` and `strchr()`

So far I've done:

```
   int i;

   char line[256];
   char *next;

   printf("Enter the string\n");
   fgets(line, 256, stdin);

   char *curr = line;

   while ((next = strchr(curr, ',')) != NULL) {
      curr = next + 1;
   }

   int len = strlen(curr);

   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      printf("%c", curr[i]);
   }
```

So as of right now if my string was: `Mary,had,a,little,lamb`

it would only just print out:

lamb

Any advice?

Comment: your while loop exhausts all commas from the string; and after that you print the last word with 1 char per line. No wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW: for once, not being allowed to use a function is a good thing. Stay away from `strtok`.

Comment: Good advice, be aware that `strtok()` would consider any sequence of commas to be equivalent to a single comma.  Also stay away from `strncpy()`.

Comment: you should emphasize more on "The program splits each word when it reaches a comma", the string printing is just to check that it worked, but the real hard task is to create a dynamic array of strings using `realloc` and `strdup`. You're miles away from the solution (and all the answers are wrong too, I deleted my simplistic one)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I posted this approach too, with a static array as the line size is limited anyway ;-) But if the OP is supposed to read multiple lines into a word dictionary, more work is needed indeed.

Comment: @chqrlie at least the OP can start from your answer and improve it.

Comment: @Karth: enjoy your new voting privileges. You can now _upvote_ as well as accepting the answer (and upvote other answers if you think they help, but you don't have to).

Comment: It's interesing how your able to use `strncpy()` but not `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is too bad they did not list the most appropriate function for this task: `strcspn()`.  You can get by with `strchr()` as posted, but there is a problem printing out the result.  You can use the `%.*s` format specifier to print a substring:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[256];

    printf("Enter the string\n");
    if (fgets(line, 256, stdin)) {
        char *curr = line;
        char *next;

        while ((next = strchr(curr, ',')) != NULL) {
            /* found a separator: print the word between curr and next */
            printf("%.*s\n", (int)(next - curr), curr);
            curr = next + 1;
        }
        /* print the last word */
        printf("%s", curr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you cannot use this somewhat advanced printf feature, you can just modify the string this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[256];

    printf("Enter the string\n");
    if (fgets(line, 256, stdin)) {
        char *curr = line;
        char *next;

        while ((next = strchr(curr, ',')) != NULL) {
            /* found a separator: replace it with '\0' */
            *next++ = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", curr);
            curr = next;
        }
        /* print the last word */
        printf("%s", curr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that you could use an even simpler solution, without even a buffer, but using `getchar()` and `putchar()` which are not on your list:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c == ',' ? '\n' : c);
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: If 2 commas next to one another mean a literal comma part of a word, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[256];

    printf("Enter the string\n");
    if (fgets(line, 256, stdin)) {
        char *curr = line;
        char *next;

        while ((next = strchr(curr, ',')) != NULL) {
            /* found a separator: print the word between curr and next */
            if (next[1] == ',') {
                next++;
                printf("%.*s", (int)(next - curr), curr);
            } else {
                printf("%.*s\n", (int)(next - curr), curr);
            }
            curr = next + 1;
        }
        /* print the last word */
        printf("%s", curr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2** Given that you are supposed to split the string into an array of pointers, the code is slightly more complicated. The array does not need to be allocated as the number of words is bound by the size of the input buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[256];
    char *array[256];
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter the string\n");
    if (fgets(line, 256, stdin)) {
        char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
        if (p != NULL) {
            *p = '\0';   /* strip the newline if any */
        }
        /* split the line into an array of words */
        n = 0;
        array[n++] = p = line;
        while ((p = strchr(p, ',')) != NULL) {
            *p++ = '\0';
            array[n++] = p;
        }
        /* print the words */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input! Your first solution works great! What if the string contains commas next to each other and I wanted to print out that 2nd comma? for instance: 12345,1234,,,123,12,1,, it prints out "12345 1234 , 123 12 1 ,"

Comment: @Karth: if the string contains 2 commas next to each other, it means there is an empty word, producing an empty line. If you want that to mean a literal comma, the code can be modified to this purpose, as posted.

Answer (score -1):

In this loop you shift **curr** to last ','

```
   while ((next = strchr(curr, ',')) != NULL) {
      curr = next + 1;
   }
```

You do it while ',' can be found. Then, ofcourse, only symbols after last comma left.
You should check current symbol with comma, if not - put it to temp string. As soon as it comma - print that temp string.